# Java library to upload and download large file (> 10GB) to CEPH?

Tags: file-upload, download, large-files, ceph

I'm writing a function to upload and download large file from CEPH (maximum is 100GB), I'm using Librados but currently Librados only allow to upload by byte[] but byte[] has limited number of elements. How to solve this problem? Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Can you please clarify what this statement "currently Librados only allow to upload by byte[] but byte[] has limited number of elements" is supposed to mean? For S3 (or plain object storage) protocol you would need to use multipart-uploads through a rados gateway. Then there's cephFS (a mounted filesystem) with a file size restriction around 1TB or so. And the last protocol is RBD, where you can map an rbd device as a regular block device to a client and do whatever you like. If that doesn't help you'll need to clarify what exactly you're trying and what works or not.

Comment: I mean the osd_max_object_size is 4GB (32-bit unsigned integer), so how can I use Librados to upload file that larger than that (10 to 100GB)?.

Comment: Every file is striped in ceph, you can't upload one file to one single OSD, that's not how ceph works.

Comment: I don't think so, if you use Librados, it will upload one file to a single OSD because if i increase the osd_max_object_size, i can upload bigger file with size equal to osd_max_object_size